# Putting JSON data into a ListView and it says I can't cast RelativeLayout to CustomAdapter?

Tags: android, json, listview, casting, custom-adapter

All the JSON parsing works and displays. The only issue is when I scroll in the ListView, then instantly I get the follow log:

```
10-16 21:49:34.383: E/InputEventReceiver(6798): Exception dispatching input event.
10-16 21:49:34.383: D/AndroidRuntime(6798): Shutting down VM
10-16 21:49:34.383: W/dalvikvm(6798): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e95a08)
10-16 21:49:34.438: E/AndroidRuntime(6798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 21:49:34.438: E/AndroidRuntime(6798): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to         com.android.test.sandroid.MainActivity$FancyAdapter$ViewHolder
10-16 21:49:34.438: E/AndroidRuntime(6798):     at     com.android.test.sandroid.MainActivity$FancyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:180)
```

So that's what happens. Here is my code is building the JSON and giving it to the List with a custom adapter. Is there a better way to do it? I followed a youtube tutorial video.

```
//End of AsyncTask

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<pData> {

    FancyAdapter() {
        super(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfNames);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(convertView);
```

**EDIT:** Removed the nosense code. The bit that counted is the holder down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `convertView.setTag(holder);` instead of `convertView.setTag(convertView);`.

This is called the *View Holder* pattern, and it allows you to avoid the `findViewById()` method call for a reused `convertView`. More information [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder).

Comment: What in the world... that fixed it. So simple. I really genuinely appreciate this. Thanks so much. 8 minutes before I can accept an answer but I will.